# Images url not working

Tags: product-images

My website name is www.shoppingara.com. I am facing a small problem on my website home page.

There are product images displayed. When we are clicking on the displayed image it is not redirecting to the product automatically. `#sing` is coming in the url. For example when I am clicking on Saree it is supposed to go to sarees category however it is not going anywhere and in url `#sing` is coming like `shoppingara.com/#sing`

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

In these items you have a # in the href link `<a ... href="#" ..>` And it does not redirect you to your categories, you should to check your links of these elements and the how you inserted them.

to redirect to some category you should put in your item:

in phtml : `<a ... href="<?php Mage::getBaseUrl().'category-url.html'?>"...`

in cms page `a ... href="{{base url''}}category-url.html"...`

This is the temporary way to do this, you can do all this properly with a collection or a load

exemple:

```
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4); //id category?>
<a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>">
```

Comment: Hi can you explain me in simple language where I have to go in admin panel (example CMS or category ) I am not a developer my developer has left the job..